# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet Hibernate+SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to fetch records from the database and I am having the above error

**This is my classs with appropriate getters and setters**

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
```

I have also create the database and inserted data into it with the below configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

This is the complete stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/spring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'usersdb.users' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
```

Please what could be wrong I new on Spring MVC with Hibernate

The complete code for User.java

```
package net.codejava.spring.model;

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: I have added the complete stacktrace..

Comment: Are you sure the table exists in your database. Error suggests table does not exist.

Comment: Can you check if you have user or users as name of the table?

Comment: The table name is users

Comment: Please post the whole code for user.java

Comment: Class `User` has annotation `@Table(name="User")` or `@Table(name="Users")` ?

Comment: I have posted the complete code for user.java

Comment: Are sure this is the complete version of `User`? Where are your entity metadatas? You gotta have a `Entity` and `Id`..

Comment: @LearningPhase http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846635/cannot-resolve-reference-to-bean-datasource-while-setting-bean-property-datas#36847100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing couple of things

```
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
@Entity
@Table(name="User")

public class User implements Serializable{
```

Comment: Where should add this

Comment: Please what is the pom dependency for using annotation

Comment: Syntax error on token "annotation", delete this token

Comment: Do I delete annotation from token entity

Comment: No. it has to look like how I mentioned in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109807/discussion-between-learningphase-and-jng).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User") or @Table(name="Users")
public class User
```

Add this dependencies to your `pom.xml`. No idea what version of hibernate or spring are you using. Just replace version if you have different one.

```
<properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-Time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you created "users" table ?  if User class is mapped to table use annotations @Entity and @Table(name="users"). try this.