# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource' .factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is the bean with this id defined in my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

This is the complete stacktrace

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
```

this is my application context file defined in my WEB-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

this is my complete web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>YummyFoods</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/JSP/welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yummyfoods.spring.servlet.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

this is my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>          
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/JSP/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate-cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Please assist me find my way.

Comment: Show your Spring application context files. From the look of things you are defining a dataSource in a DispatcherServlet context configuration file. And the entityManagerFactory in a root application context file. Beans in the root application context cannot reference those in the servlet application context file. You need to move your dataSource bean to the other xml config file

Comment: If you have a `web.xml`, post it...

Comment: Yes. I do. Do I show it

Comment: @JnG Could you show your hibernate-context.xml file?

Comment: Where is your hibernate-context.xml? and where did you declare entityManagerFactory?

Comment: I only have spring-servlet.xml file in my WEB-INF folder

Comment: How did you import other configurations? Post full details of all config files...

Comment: But your error say's Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/hibernate-context.xml]

Comment: I have included my spring-servlet.xml file

Comment: This is weird..You're defining a `SessionFactory` in `spring-servlet` and `EntityManagerFactory` in `hibernate-context`. Don't do that with yourself! Also, post the `hibernate-context` file. If you used the hibernate configuration as your root context, as ekem chitsiga said, you can't reference `DataSource` from its child context.

Comment: @Unknown This is all the files I have for my configuration and this why I am looking for assistance

Comment: you should define beans and commons stuff in `applicationContext` and servlet specific stuff in `spring-servlet.xml`

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, How you can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the look of things you are defining a dataSource in a `DispatcherServlet` context configuration file i.e `spring-servlet.xml` as you have specified. And the `entityManagerFactory` in a *root application context* file. Beans in the root application context cannot reference those in the servlet application context file. You need to move your `dataSource` bean to the `hibernate-context.xml` file.

Comment: What about META-NF/spring/hibernate-context.xml. As i said define dataSource in that file and not spring-servlet.xml

Comment: I only have spring-servlet.xml file and applicationContext.xml in my WEB-INF folder

Answer (score -1):

What comes with your dependecies? I think you should include your datasource def in `applicationContext.xml` and then the hibernate thing should be happy.

So...
the

```
<bean id="dataSource"
         class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
         p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
         p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
         p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <property name="configLocation">
             <value>classpath:hibernate-cfg.xml</value>
         </property>
         <property name="configurationClass">
             <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
         </property>
         <property name="hibernateProperties">
             <props>
                 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
                 <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
             </props>
         </property>
     </bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven />
     <bean id="transactionManager"
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
         <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     </bean>
```

goes in `applicationContext.xml` and is removed from `spring-servlet.xml`

Then the hibernate-cfg.xml wich is embeded in the Session factory def should find it's data source and be happy at loading.

It's better to isolate servlet mapping and mvc definitions from back end stuff (bean factory etc...) as it is easier to change it in the future if needed.

With what do you build your app?

Comment: Please, if you have a comment, do comment. This isn't an answer

Comment: i don't think giving full code to answer this will be helpfull to the op but it can be done.

Comment: Post snippets if you think so

Comment: I cant find this classpath:hibernate-cfg.xml org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration ${jdbc.dialect} true  in my spring-servlet class

Comment: look at your sessionFactory def (my fomating was out of order in my first atempt sorry).

Comment: I dont have this xml file in my project folder <value>classpath:hibernate-cfg.xml</value> or is it okay?

Comment: you should have it in one of your dependencies it find it as it try to create beans from it as said in your exception trace...

Comment: @Nemesis what would be the content of this file? You did not include it in your answer

Comment: @JnG hello create a chat request and send my way